# I want to hide a text box that doesn't have id from js file. I am not able to figure out, Kindly let me know

Tags: javascript, html, slickgrid

There is a text box in header, above the check boxes in slick grid that i want to hide. This text box is not having id so i am not sure how to hide without the id.

This is the HTML part

```
 <div id="figuresGrid">
        <div id="figuresByClassGrid" class="clearBg dispNone" style="width: 820px; height: 600px;"></div>
  </div>
```

This is the Javascript part

```
var figGridColumns = [
            { id: "A", name: resources.Number, field: "Number", sortable: true, width: 165 },
            { id: "B", name: "BOM", field: "BOM", width: 115 },
            { id: "C", name: resources.Class, field: "Class", width: 125 },
            {
                id: "updated",
                name: "Updated",
                field: "UpdatedDisplay",
                width: 165,
                formatter: function (row, cell, value) {
                    return "<span>" + value + "</span>";
                }
            },
            { id: "user", name: resources.User, field: "User", width: 165 }
        ];

        var gridOptions = { enableCheckBox: true, cssClass: "checkBoxStyle", showHeaderRow: true, enableCellNavigation: true, headerRowHeight: 30, filter: filter };
        viewByClassGrid = new gg.sacs.SlickGridWrapper("#figuresByClassGrid", figGridColumns, "FigureId", "Number", gridOptions, figFilters);
```

The text box i want to hide is being shown before the Number field in header row.

Comment: Just post the HTML rather than trying to describe it, please.

Comment: Is that particular text box alone is in any <div> ? Then try to hide with that.. `$("#divID").find("input[type=text]").hide(); `

Comment: the text box is not alone, there are other text boxes along with it and they are in header row.

Answer (score 0):

find is their any class for that text box.

or

add class to that textbox, then you can do whatever you want.